# Python dictionary update surprise

Tags: python, dictionary

Working on some code to decompose composite file names I was surprised to find that:

```py
d = {}
d['file'] = d.get('file', {}).update({'two': 'file_two'})
print(d)
```

returns
{'file': None}

but I can get my desired result with

```py
e =  {}
temp = e.get('one', {})
temp.update({'two': 'file_two'})
e['file'] = temp
print(e)
```

which returns
{'file': {'two': 'file_two'}}

Please would someone explain why it's not possible to remove the use of the temporary variable.
Thanks

Comment: because `dict.update` returns `None` and you assign this to `d["file"]`

Comment: You could use the dictionary merge syntax: `d['file'] = {**d.get('file', {}), 'two': 'file_two'}`

Comment: Or even just `d.setdefault('file', {})['two'] = 'file_two'` ...

Comment: Command chaining is not desirable in Python since it reduces readability. (some libraries encourage it anyways) This is also why pretty much everything in the standard library does not return what is already known.

Comment: thanks folks, some great learning points there.  I think the setdefault() was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You assign the return value of `update` to `d['file']`.

[`dict.update` returns `None`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update). Hence `d['file']` is set to `None`.